# How can I stop cloning my application files on GitHub?

Tags: github, git-clone, visual-studio-mac

I want to stop cloning my application files to Github, How can I do that completely and remove the circle status on each solution files?

Environment: Visual Studio for Mac

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you intending to have git ignore those files completely?

You can use a [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file (`.gitignore`) in the root working directory of your project to specify which files to ignore. In there, specify a filename per line in that file, or a whole directory to be ignored (eg: `Shared/*`).

You'll also need to remove those files from your git repo, since they've already been committed.

Copy-pasting from [here](https://devconnected.com/how-to-remove-files-from-git-commit/):

1. Unstage the file

   `git reset HEAD newfile`
2. Remove the file from git

   `git rm --cached newfile`

Deleting the file will count as a commit, so you'll need to `git push` once you're done.

Also note that the file(s) and their contents will still exist in the git commit history, so this isn't a good idea if the goal is removing files with sensitive info.